# What is an in-memory API?

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a User Story where I am asked to make a call to a in-memory API to verify a token. I have to do it in React. So what is an in memory API? How do I use it in a case like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its purest form, it basically means that the data the API handles is not stored on a persistent storage but on the computer dynamic memory, thus not persisted on application restart. By extension, generally, an in-memory API is also local to the application, not located on a remote server. The main purpose of such API's is for mocking and testing purposes.

In your case that API is most probably a service that simulates remote requests but actually returns mock data stored in the dynamic memory.

---

Example:

```
const VALID_TOKENS = [
    'ABCDFAX',
    'ABBBBBC',
    'USDAZXV'
];

class TokenService {
    verifyTokenAsync(token) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(VALID_TOKENS.includes(token));                
            }, 250);
        });
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
const service = new TokenService();

const verifyTokenResult = await verifyTokenAsync('ABCDFAX');
```

As you see, the `verifyTokenAsync` method doesn't do an actual remote call to a server to verify the `token` but checks in it's local cache `VALID_TOKENS` and resolves the result after `250ms` as to simulate network delay.

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide un example of such a service? @zhulien that would be awesome

Comment: @Manzana I've posted an example in the answer.